# HTTP requests not working on aws ec2

Tags: http, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am building an app in node.js and I’m using AWS EC2 to host it. However, my HTTP requests are not working.

My app is split into two repositories: `app-ui` and `app-server`. `app-server` contains all of my server side code/API’s. In app-ui, I am making simple POST requests such as:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://ec2-xx-xxx-xx/api/users",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(a) {
        console.log(a);
    }
});
```

However, I keep getting the `net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` error.

Does anyone know what might be happening?

Comment: There was a major outage in AWS East Coast server check the health of your instance

Comment: Hi - according to the aws console, my aws ec2 instance is running fine.. also, the code in `app-ui` works fine since I'm able to each it by going to `http://ec2-xx-xxx-xx.com/3001`

Comment: The next culprit are your security groups attached to this service, make sure  you have inbound rules are correct.

Comment: that did it! i needed to add an inbound rule for port 3002, which is the port my `app-server` runs on... thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add an inbound rule for the security group attached to your server for the specific port you're using.

Comment: I've opened the port in security group inbound rules, from 3000 till 3003. However, when the apps run on 3002 or 3003, I couldn't open it up in browser, but for 3000 and 3001 it works fine. Do you know what is the issue? is it kind of specific whitelisted ports from AWS/EC2?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue this is because the amazon servers were down today, but take a look on your server to see if it is working in my case:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 status
```

Response:

`Active: active (running) since Wed 2017-03-01 02:21:53 UTC; 2h 3min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)`

Apparently the S3 was one of the services down and also the routing system, if your server was located on AWS EST side you will find this issue, this affected several apps like HockeyApp and Trello

Take a look on the current status: status.aws.amazon.com
Of course assuming that you have the security groups, the elastic or static ip's set and configured and that you see this issue on all your site and not just on your API

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same situation. I managed it. Go to AWS -> login -> ec2 -> select the options in the left sidebar "security and groups". then select your default instance on the right side that is listed in the table then clicked the action button on the top of the table. that will show the inbound menu.

there you click the "add rule" button. there the type is "custom TCP" then you give port 8080 or whatever you prepare. then save it.

Now go ahead with postman it will work. enjoy your work. !!!!